# Using WPF For bar Graphs

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I Want to use Graphs in WPF.At the moment I am using WPF toolkit to make graphs in WPF but cant find the resources for the step by step procedure to modify the bar graph (colour,size etc).Can anyone please help me or give me the necessary url for doing so...Also can this be used to make 3d charts or if there is any other open source stuff I can use please do mention it.Thanks

Comment: you could also use a ListBox see [this example](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/wpf-listbox-as-bar-chart.html)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/)?

For me, it's the best free charts library available for WPF.

Comment: can you please tell me the link to the tutorial for this Dynamic Data Display?

Comment: This is the disadvantage of this library.. It's quit hard to use if you're new to WPF. The very basics are on the following link, sample source is included in the download package: http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=D3v1

Comment: although i have referenced the dll still it is giving me error that d3 is not found ?...can you please help

Comment: add project references to: DynamicDataDisplay.dll, DynamicDataDisplay.Coastline.dll, DynamicDataDisplay.Controls.dll, ynamicDataDisplay.Maps.dll and in your xaml add `xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"`

Comment: did all the above....i am using visual studio 10 and .net 4...is it because of that>?

Comment: I don't think so. But my last try was with .NET 3.5 .. What's the exact error message? Did you build the project after adding the text to your xaml file? The designer of Visual Studio cannot load new referenced libraries without a new build.

Comment: i tries with building the project but no breakthrough....any other source for bar graph in WPF can you suggest?